# How to find spesific character only inside square bracket in regex

Tags: regex

I want to find out V letter only inside square brackets from this string below :

`1. ADCVV[EO]-[asV]-[avs]-[VAS]
2. ADCVV[EO][a]
3. ADCVV[EO][a]v
4. ADCVV[EO]v[a]`

my expectation string match only number 1

I have try with `\[((.*[vV]).*)\]` but it will find out number 1 and 4

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the brackets always balanced? Eg a `[` is always paired with a `]`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance no, it is dynamic. Any letter allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match a `[`, followed by zero or more non-bracket characters, followed by a `V`, followed by more non-bracket characters, followed by `]`:

```
\[[^[\]]*V[^[\]]*\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/GstRUW/2

Comment: Solved. you save my time. Thank you

Comment: Even shorter if you want: `\[[^][]*V[^][]*\]` - switches `[` and `]` in the character sets and allows you to remove backslash - will not work in some regex engines. `\[[^]]*V[^]]*\]` if they're always balanced and never nested.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/(?<=\])[^[\]\W]+(?=\[)/`.

This makes use of both a positive lookbehind and a positive lookahead to only extract characters between `]` and a `[`.

This can be seen selecting only the `v` [here](https://regex101.com/r/O8t1Fw/1/).

```js
const regex = /(?<=\])[^[\]\W]+(?=\[)/;

console.log('ADCVV[EO]-[asV]-[avs]-[VAS]'.match(regex));
console.log('ADCVV[EO][a]'.match(regex));
console.log('ADCVV[EO][a]v'.match(regex));
console.log('ADCVV[EO]v[a]'.match(regex));
```